# Weyl group is the set of type preserving automorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory, buildings

So in Suzuki’s group theory I we have a proposition 3.20 (ii) which says if we have a building $ \Delta $ and $\Sigma $ an apartment with $C \in \Sigma $ a chamber. Also we have $B \in \Sigma $ is any element. If we have maps $\phi, \psi : \Sigma \rightarrow \Sigma $ such that $\phi(B), \psi (B) \subset C $ and both $\phi $ and $\psi $ leave every vertex of $C$ invariant, then $\phi = \psi $ on every vertex of $B$.

Now then on the next page it gives a definition, it says that the common value in (3.20)(ii) will be denoted by $\rho_C (B)$. Two elements $B , B’ \in \Sigma $ are said to have the same type of $\rho_C(B)=\rho_C(B’)$.

I’m a bit confused as to what they mean by the common value, I don’t know exactly what they’re referring to. Anyone know what they are saying?

To give some further information it then says that the Weyl group of $\Sigma $ is the set of type preserving automorphisms of $\Sigma$.

Comment: I don't have that source, so I don't know the context with certainty, but there is a uniqueness theorem (by induction) for type-preserving maps of various sorts. Possibly "secretly" these maps are the canonical retractions of the apartment to the fixed chamber?

Comment: I had a thought that they might be referring to the retraction since they also used this notation $\rho $ for the retraction map.

Comment: You should not post simultaneously here and [at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724851/weyl-group-is-the-set-of-type-preserving-automorphisms).

Comment: This seems like an English thing, not a math thing, aren't they just saying that $\phi$ and $\psi$ take the same value on $B$, i.e., $\phi(B)=\psi(B)$ (they have a "common value" on $B$), so let's write $\rho_C(B)$ instead of deciding whether to write $\phi(B)$ or $\psi(B)$ all the time?

Comment: Sure but it says that $\phi = \psi $ on the vertices of$B$. Does this mean that they’re that $\psi (B)= \phi (B) $? Also, not only this, why should such a map exist in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, I mean these are simplicial maps - if they agree on each vertex of $B$ then they agree on $B$. As for "why should such a map exist in the first place", well, you can always fold along a gallery to bring your arbitrary simplex into the fundamental chamber, but I don't know what you're "allowed to know" at this stage of the book.